# Priority queue with custom type class gets TypeError("'>' not supported between instances of 'PrioritizedItem' and 'int'",)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, typing, python-dataclasses

I am doing A* search and need to store information in priority queue. But I want the priority queue to compare **only one field** of my data. So I designed a class`PrioritizedItem` for priori queue. However, my program keeps running forever. I wrote some simple test code to reproduce this error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
import queue

@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
    hint: float
    current: tuple=field(compare=False)
    path: list=field(compare= False)
trace=[(0, 0)]
temp=PrioritizedItem(hint=14, current=(0, 0) ,path=trace) 
priori_queue = queue.PriorityQueue(temp ) #queue contains current location
priori_queue
```

[image]

After initialization, my priority queue `prior_queue` is still empty. Manually  add the element `temp` even gives me an error TypeError("'>' not supported between instances of 'PrioritizedItem' and 'int'",). Looks like my type class `PriortizedItem` is missing some piece. How to add that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `temp` in `PriorityQueue(temp)`, but the only argument to [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) is `maxsize`, which should be an integer. The default is `0`, which means the queue grows with no size limit.

```
priori_queue = queue.PriorityQueue()
priori_queue.put(temp)
```